# IIS Rewrite Rules: I need an IIS URL Rewrite pattern which gives me required url

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I need an IIS7 URL Rewrite pattern which gives me url like www.mydomain.com/username/signup.

i am creating a Friendly URL Patterns in IIS URL Rewrite

my normal URL would look like this

```
 http://www.mydoamin.com/signup.aspx?usr="username"
```

and the options available in IIS like

```
http://www.mydoamin.com/signup/usr/username

http://www.mydoamin.com/usr/username

http://www.mydoamin.com/signup/username
```

but i need a pattern to rewrite my url as

```
 http://www.mydomain.com/username/signup.
```

is it possible to rewrite url like this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an attempt, haven't tested this.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite To Clean Url">
      <match url="^signup.aspx?user=([0-9a-zA-Z]+)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/signup" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

You can reference a capture group in your match pattern using R:N where N is a reference to the capture group.[1]

> ```
> <rewrite>
>   <rules>
>     <rule name="Rewrite to article.aspx">
>       <match url="^article/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
>       <action type="Rewrite" url="article.aspx?id={R:1}&title={R:2}" />
>     </rule>
>   </rules>
> </rewrite>
> ```
>
> For example in this pattern:
>
> ```
> ^(www\.)(.*)$
> ```
>
> For the string: www.foo.com the back-references will be indexed as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> {C:0} - www.foo.com
> {C:1} - www.
> {C:2} - foo.com
> ```

Reference:

[1] http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

[2] http://forums.iis.net/t/1187281.aspx?Capture+the+back+reference+in+the+content+URLs

Comment: thanx for the references.

Answer (score 0):

It's Working perfect...for www.mydomain.com/username/signup

```
            <rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^Signup\.aspx$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^usr=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}/Signup" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([^/]+)/?Signup$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="Signup.aspx?uname={R:1}" />
            </rule>
```